# removing specific lines with specific string

Tags: awk

```
awk '!/#EXT/ $1' input > output
```

does not remove all the lines that contains #EXT. output is blank. I am using os x 10.10.
input file is:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:654,filenameSong1.aiff
/Users/myname/Music/folder1/filenameSong1.aiff
#EXTINF:198,filenamesong2.mp4
/Users/myname/Music/folder1/subfolder2/filenameSong2.mp4
#EXTINF:217,filenameSong3.mp3
/Users/myname/Music/folder1/subfolder3/filenameSong3.mp3
#EXTINF:341,filenameSong4.mp4
/Users/myname/Music/folder1/subfolder3/filenameSong4.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
awk '!/^#EXT/' file
```

A line is printed when the condition return 1 (true). When `/^#EXT/` (or `/#EXT/` if you prefer) succeeds, it returns 1 that is negated with the `!`.

`!/#EXT/ $1` returns the result of `!/#EXT/` concatened with the first field `$1`, so for the first line: `0#EXTM3U` that is evaluated to true. That's why your code doesn't work.

Note: If the newline characters of your file are CR, you can define it as input record separator in awk and set the output record separator to LF, like this:

```
awk -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\n' '!/^#EXT/' file
```

Comment: still get blank output!

Comment: could be the problem with my version of awk for OS X?

Comment: Works for me on OS X.

Comment: found the problem! my input file is Classic Mac (CR) and must be changed to UNIX(LF) before awk can do its work.

Comment: @siamak: you don't need to do this change, see the note at the end of my answer.

Comment: Not sure which note you referring. but both ways does not work unless make the change to (LF).

Comment: @siamak: One more time, it works for me (tested with CR).

Comment: thanks. I do not know why only works here only if file is changed to (LF). But that is o.k.

Comment: Great Just saw your last comment. Now is working with CR.

Comment: for the record, same problem with                                                  awk '!/^#EXT/' file. only awk -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\n' '!/^#EXT/' file or change the file to LF prior to using awk will work. But again thank you. I can now make work around this issue with my script.